# Executing unit tests of Azure with a local storage emulator is very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, azure, azure-compute-emulator

Me and some colleagues are facing some very annoying problems executing the unit tests of our Azure services.

We have pretty nice workstations equipped with Xeon CPUs @2.67GHz, 6GB of RAM, and SSD disks. The strange thing is that for some of us the execution requires around 15 minutes, but one of us executes them in 2 minutes or so (and he has our same configuration machine). We weren't able to find out different configurations of SQL Express or of the Azure SDK installation.

I don't know which details I can give you to explain better what it happens, if you have any suggestion to improve the question I'll be glad to edit it.

Any ideas on what to check, change, try?

Comment: There's really not enough information here to help: No idea of the type of operations you're running. You might want to start by measuring call timings in your unit tests. At least you can then come back with info on which call(s) are taking a long time.

Comment: I suggest you use real storage. There are a number of differences, so you're better off testing with the real thing.